# Finding the minimum bounding box of a convex hull

Tags: java, c++, opengl, vertex, convex-hull

Let's say that I have a n sided convex hull, now how do I get the Right/Left Top/Bottom corners of said convex hull, now let's say that maybe N is 3 and the triangle coordinates are 0,0 50,0 0,50 or something else, we know what the corners are and that 0,50 counts as both the Right top and left, so is there some way to get this rather than what I have here, where     Left_Bottom and so on are vectors and     values is a vector array

```
    Left_Bottom = values[0];
    Left_Top = values[0];
    Right_Bottom = values[0];
    Right_Top = values[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (!Left_Bottom.XisLess(values[i])) {
            if (Left_Bottom.YisLess(values[i])) {
                Left_Bottom = values[i];
            }
        }

        if (!Left_Top.XisLess(values[i])) {
            if (!Left_Top.YisLess(values[i])) {
                Left_Top = values[i];
            }
        }

        if (Right_Bottom.XisLess(values[i])) {
            if (Right_Bottom.YisLess(values[i])) {
                Right_Bottom = values[i];
            }
        }

        if (Right_Top.XisLess(values[i])) {
            if (!Right_Top.YisLess(values[i])) {
                Right_Top = values[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In what situation will you be using this, i.e. what is the reason you're searching for a better solution? Also: what is the "values" vector? Just a vector containing all points in the hull or something else?

Comment: Also, your title and your question are a little bit out of sync; are you trying to find all corners or just four? (Top/Bottom/Left/Right)

Comment: just the four most extreme corners, for the application of 2d lighting, that I have down though, in opengl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are looking for the **problem of finding the convex hull of a finite set of points**, take a look at [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms). You can find several solutions to do this in O(n*log n)

[image]

2. If you are just looking for the four corners of the bounding rectangle of this convex hull, actually you are looking for **minimum bounding box** for the convex hull.

   - If the bounding box is parallel to the coordinate axes, just find the `min_x`, `min_y`, `max_x` and `max_y` among all these convex hull points. Then the four corners (clockwisely) are:

     1. (min_x, min_y)
     2. (max_x, min_y)
     3. (max_x, max_y)
     4. (min_x, max_y)

[image]

- If the bounding box is not parallel to the coordinate axes, this becomes complex. Check out the references introduced in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms) and [here](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/rexrepos/posts/diagBounding.html) for the implementation.

[image]

Comment: this helps, but what I need is the corners of the bounding box to be on the most extreme corners of the convex hull, thanks though, this helps

Comment: @Slymodi check out the second link I mentioned, where you can find the solution of this. Good luck.

Comment: See this Java Implementation:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23956275