# oriented minimum bounding box

Tags: java, bounding-box

I'm looking for a java code to create a oriented minimum bounding box with points, which have a lat/lon value.  I've already created a minimum bounding box, like this:

```
public Mbb boundingBox() {
    Point ll, ur; 
    Mbb bBox;
    int id =1;
    ll = new Point(id, Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE); 
    ur= new Point(id,-1*Double.MAX_VALUE, -1*Double.MAX_VALUE);

    if (this.pg.size() <=1)   
        return null;

    double minLat = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double minLong = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double maxLat = Double.MAX_VALUE*-1;
    double maxLong = Double.MAX_VALUE*-1;

    for (Point testPoint: this.pg) {
        double lat = testPoint.getLat();
        double lon = testPoint.getLon();

        if(minLat>lat)
            minLat=lat;
        if(minLong>lon)
            minLong=lon;
        if(maxLat<lat)
            maxLat=lat;
        if(maxLong<lon)
            maxLong=lon;
    }

    ll.setLat(minLat);
    ll.setLon(minLong);
    ur.setLat(maxLat);
    ur.setLon(maxLong);

    bBox= new Mbb(id, ll, ur); 
    return bBox;
}
```

But this is not an oriented one. Has anybody an idea how to orient my bounding box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The computation if the minimum oriented bounding box is not so trivial. But one approach is described in an answer to https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/22895 . The answer links to a Java implementation, but this is obviously part of a larger framework. However, I implemented the approach here as an example:

[image: MinObb]

The computation of the convex hull is made with a code snippet taken from [convex-hull at Google code](https://code.google.com/p/convex-hull/source/browse/Convex+Hull/src/algorithms/FastConvexHull.java?r=4) - it's not the nicest implementation, but was the first one that I found, and does the job.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MinOrientedBoundingBoxTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new MinOrientedBoundingBoxTestPanel());
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MinOrientedBoundingBoxTestPanel extends JPanel 
    implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
    private final List<Point2D> points;
    private Point2D draggedPoint = null;

    MinOrientedBoundingBoxTestPanel()
    {
        points = new ArrayList<Point2D>();

        Random r = new Random(0);
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        {
            double x = 200 + r.nextDouble() * 200;
            double y = 200 + r.nextDouble() * 200;
            points.add(new Point2D.Double(x,y));
        }

        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,  
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        drawPoints(g, points);

        boolean showConvexHull = false;
        showConvexHull = true;
        if (showConvexHull)
        {
            List<Point2D> convexHullPoints = 
                MinOrientedBoundingBoxComputer.computeConvexHullPoints(
                    points);
            Path2D convexHullPath = 
                MinOrientedBoundingBoxComputer.createPath(
                    convexHullPoints);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.draw(convexHullPath);
        }

        List<Point2D> minObbCorners = 
            MinOrientedBoundingBoxComputer.computeCorners(points);

        Path2D p = MinOrientedBoundingBoxComputer.createPath(minObbCorners);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.draw(p);
    }

    static void drawPoints(Graphics2D g, List<Point2D> points)
    {
        double r = 3;
        for (Point2D point : points)
        {
            double x = point.getX();
            double y = point.getY();
            g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(
                x-r, y-r, r+r, r+r));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (draggedPoint != null)
        {
            draggedPoint.setLocation(e.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        draggedPoint = null;
        double thresholdSquared = 10*10;
        double minDs = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Point2D point : points)
        {
            double ds = point.distanceSq(e.getPoint());
            if (ds < thresholdSquared && ds < minDs)
            {
                minDs = ds;
                draggedPoint = point;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        draggedPoint = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }
}


class MinOrientedBoundingBoxComputer
{
    static List<Point2D> computeCorners(List<Point2D> points)
    {
        List<Point2D> convexHullPoints = 
            computeConvexHullPoints(points);
        int alignmentPointIndex = 
            computeAlignmentPointIndex(convexHullPoints);
        Rectangle2D r = computeAlignedBounds(
            convexHullPoints, alignmentPointIndex);

        List<Point2D> alignedCorners = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        alignedCorners.add(new Point2D.Double(r.getMinX(), r.getMinY()));
        alignedCorners.add(new Point2D.Double(r.getMaxX(), r.getMinY()));
        alignedCorners.add(new Point2D.Double(r.getMaxX(), r.getMaxY()));
        alignedCorners.add(new Point2D.Double(r.getMinX(), r.getMaxY()));

        Point2D center = convexHullPoints.get(alignmentPointIndex);
        double angleRad = computeEdgeAngleRad(
            convexHullPoints, alignmentPointIndex);

        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.concatenate(
            AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(
                center.getX(), center.getY()));
        at.concatenate(
            AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angleRad));

        List<Point2D> corners = transform(alignedCorners, at);
        return corners;
    }

    private static int computeAlignmentPointIndex(
        List<Point2D> points)
    {
        double minArea = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int minAreaIndex = -1;
        for (int i=0; i<points.size(); i++)
        {
            Rectangle2D r = computeAlignedBounds(points, i);
            double area = r.getWidth() * r.getHeight();

            if (area < minArea)
            {
                minArea = area;
                minAreaIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return minAreaIndex;
    }

    private static double computeEdgeAngleRad(
        List<Point2D> points, int index)
    {
        int i0 = index;
        int i1 = (i0+1)%points.size();
        Point2D p0 = points.get(i0);
        Point2D p1 = points.get(i1);
        double dx = p1.getX() - p0.getX();
        double dy = p1.getY() - p0.getY();
        double angleRad = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        return angleRad;
    }

    private static Rectangle2D computeAlignedBounds(
        List<Point2D> points, int index)
    {
        Point2D p0 = points.get(index);
        double angleRad = computeEdgeAngleRad(points, index);
        AffineTransform at = createTransform(-angleRad, p0);
        List<Point2D> transformedPoints = transform(points, at);
        Rectangle2D bounds = computeBounds(transformedPoints);
        return bounds;
    }

    private static AffineTransform createTransform(
        double angleRad, Point2D center)
    {
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.concatenate(
            AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angleRad));
        at.concatenate(
            AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(
                -center.getX(), -center.getY()));
        return at;
    }

    private static List<Point2D> transform(
        List<Point2D> points, AffineTransform at)
    {
        List<Point2D> result = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        for (Point2D p : points)
        {
            Point2D tp = at.transform(p, null);
            result.add(tp);
        }
        return result;
    }


    private static Rectangle2D computeBounds(
        List<Point2D> points)
    {
        double minX = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double minY = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double maxX = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double maxY = -Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Point2D p : points)
        {
            double x = p.getX();
            double y = p.getY();
            minX = Math.min(minX, x);
            minY = Math.min(minY, y);
            maxX = Math.max(maxX, x);
            maxY = Math.max(maxY, y);
        }
        return new Rectangle2D.Double(minX, minY, maxX-minX, maxY-minY);
    }

    static Path2D createPath(List<Point2D> points)
    {
        Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
        for (int i=0; i<points.size(); i++)
        {
            Point2D p = points.get(i);
            double x = p.getX();
            double y = p.getY();
            if (i == 0)
            {
                path.moveTo(x, y);
            }
            else
            {
                path.lineTo(x, y);
            }
        }
        path.closePath();
        return path;
    }


    static List<Point2D> computeConvexHullPoints(List<Point2D> points)
    {
        // NOTE: Converting from Point2D to Point here
        // because the FastConvexHull class expects
        // the points with integer coordinates. 
        // This should be generalized to Point2D!
        ArrayList<Point> ps = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for (Point2D p : points)
        {
            ps.add(new Point((int)p.getX(), (int)p.getY()));
        }
        List<Point> convexHull = FastConvexHull.execute(ps);
        List<Point2D> result = new ArrayList<Point2D>();
        for (Point p : convexHull)
        {
            double x = p.getX();
            double y = p.getY();
            result.add(new Point2D.Double(x,y));
        }
        return result;
    }
}



// From https://code.google.com/p/convex-hull/source/browse/
//     Convex+Hull/src/algorithms/FastConvexHull.java?r=4
// Under GPL2 license
// (Not a "nice" implementation, but the first one that 
// I found with a websearch. Maybe, when I'm bored, I'll
// replace it with another one...)
class FastConvexHull
{
    public static ArrayList<Point> execute(ArrayList<Point> points)
    {
        ArrayList<Point> xSorted = (ArrayList<Point>) points.clone();
        Collections.sort(xSorted, new XCompare());

        int n = xSorted.size();

        Point[] lUpper = new Point[n];

        lUpper[0] = xSorted.get(0);
        lUpper[1] = xSorted.get(1);

        int lUpperSize = 2;

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            lUpper[lUpperSize] = xSorted.get(i);
            lUpperSize++;

            while (lUpperSize > 2 &&
                !rightTurn(lUpper[lUpperSize - 3], lUpper[lUpperSize - 2],
                    lUpper[lUpperSize - 1]))
            {
                // Remove the middle point of the three last
                lUpper[lUpperSize - 2] = lUpper[lUpperSize - 1];
                lUpperSize--;
            }
        }

        Point[] lLower = new Point[n];

        lLower[0] = xSorted.get(n - 1);
        lLower[1] = xSorted.get(n - 2);

        int lLowerSize = 2;

        for (int i = n - 3; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            lLower[lLowerSize] = xSorted.get(i);
            lLowerSize++;

            while (lLowerSize > 2 &&
                !rightTurn(lLower[lLowerSize - 3], lLower[lLowerSize - 2],
                    lLower[lLowerSize - 1]))
            {
                // Remove the middle point of the three last
                lLower[lLowerSize - 2] = lLower[lLowerSize - 1];
                lLowerSize--;
            }
        }

        ArrayList<Point> result = new ArrayList<Point>();

        for (int i = 0; i < lUpperSize; i++)
        {
            result.add(lUpper[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < lLowerSize - 1; i++)
        {
            result.add(lLower[i]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static boolean rightTurn(Point a, Point b, Point c)
    {
        return (b.x - a.x) * (c.y - a.y) - (b.y - a.y) * (c.x - a.x) > 0;
    }

    private static class XCompare implements Comparator<Point>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Point o1, Point o2)
        {
            return (new Integer(o1.x)).compareTo(new Integer(o2.x));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Note that it might fail when multiple points have the exact same X coordinate.

Comment: @EricDuminil I haven't tested the specific solution posted here for corner cases, but from quickly skimming over the code now, I think that it *might* fail due to the convex hull computation? However, the bounding box computation is part of my library at https://github.com/javagl/Geom/tree/master/src/main/java/de/javagl/geom , which also contains a convex hull implementation that *might* be more robust (although it's hard to make sure that there *really* is no corner case in which it fails...)

Comment: @Thanks for the answer. I tested it on some 3D buildings and the `FastConvexHull` computation failed with `[Point2D.Double[447746.474, 5536399.344], Point2D.Double[447720.711, 5536399.344], Point2D.Double[447720.711, 5536455.141], Point2D.Double[447720.711, 5536455.141], Point2D.Double[447746.474, 5536455.141], Point2D.Double[447746.474, 5536455.141], Point2D.Double[447720.711, 5536399.344], Point2D.Double[447746.474, 5536399.344]]`. It returned a flat polygon with only 2 vertices instead of the expected 4. Sorting by `X` and then by `Y` solved the problem.

Comment: @EricDuminil I just did a quick test with the implementation from my library with your points, and it seemed to work: The result was 4 corners. (I also moved the points by (-447000, -5536300) to inspect the result visually, with https://github.com/javagl/Geom/blob/master/src/test/java/de/javagl/geom/MinOrientedBoundingBoxTest.java )