# Fitting a rectangle from GPS co-ordinantes. in C++

Tags: c++, points, convex-hull

G'day, I've been trying to read up on how to fit a rectangle onto a set of points (On a cartesian plane for now). 
Often the post would be talking about or refer to Convex Hulls and O(n) solutions.

Example:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/finding-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points

Python

[python: Help to implement an algorithm to find the minimum-area-rectangle for given points in order to compute the major and minor axis length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542855/python-help-to-implement-an-algorithm-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-gi/33619018#33619018)

Java
[oriented minimum bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905127/oriented-minimum-bounding-box/23956275#23956275)

I am unsure of where to start, I am not looking for actual code, I'm looking for a starting point. As the modules are all written in Python or Java or R. I'm having trouble on how to understand the code and write my own in C++.

The scope of the project is simply receive a bunch of GPS coordinates, try to draw Minimum sized rectangle enclosing those ordinates. Thank you.

Comment: [This answer lays out what needs to be done in steps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/22904/26388). What else do you need? As far as I can see, it's simply exploiting the fact that *some* (one) pair of vertices from your convex hull will lie on a face of the rectangle and going from there.

Comment: I'm more concerned the libraries won't be in C++, the method makes sense. 
Do you think I should just try my best to convert the Java to C++?

Comment: Libraries for what? GPS? Computing a convex hull? Those are all commonly available tools in pretty much every language.

Comment: This is what happens when I know nothing and as the wrong questions!

So you're telling me I can find the algorithms below


import com.vividsolutions.jts.algorithm.ConvexHull;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;


import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon;


Ok that answers my concern. Thank you.

Comment: I'd start [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/convex_hull.html) for reasonable quality implementations.